# How do I get perfect chest shape for men?

Tags: workout, chest

I am in fitness since 4 years and doing lots of sports and also going to gym. I have tried all kind of chest exercises whether in GYM or HOUSE. But still I did not achieve the perfect chest shape with some muscles. Maybe I am doing some wrong stuff. Please share your idea or experience that how to get some muscles in your chest and also a nice looking shape.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. : I don't want a big body building chest but nice shaped athletic chest.

Comment: push ups, then more push-ups variations, and then some more. Repeat.

Comment: @dakatine: Is there any ideal plan for a week or month to follow with variations of pushups? That would help.

Comment: Pushups are very limited unless you find a way to add resistance. The bench is your friend. Incline bench press, decline bench press, flat bench press, using barbell or dumbell. A variation between these will almost certainly give you a bigger chest.

Comment: We each have our own idea of the "perfect chest" shape.  Your interpretation would dictate how, and, with what exercises you train your chest.

Comment: oh, you can add plenty of resistance. Do that raising your legs on a chair.

then do one hand push-ups against a wall.

Then progress to one-hand pushups with raised feet. And tell me if the ground is "resistant" enough then. :) @Alec

Comment: I highly suggest looking at youtube. There are a bunch of trainers that give advice and workout suggestions about chest workout. I use it and follow the videos as I work out.

Comment: This. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHvMDlQ8Zyk

Comment: @Dakatine - Yes, I'm familiar with the pushup variations. But they still don't provide the same resistance (and thus progressive overload) that you'd be able to experience with weights.

Comment: @Dakatine you can always add plates on your back when doing pushups for resistance as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing exercises and how many sets or series will depend on your body structure and your experience, but there are some assumptions.

If you are talking about build more muscle mass in your chest region, in a "bulking" context, you should priorize [compound exercises](http://www.exrx.net/WeightTraining/Glossary.html#anchor1271511) which have chest region as one of its important targets, but these exercises, for example, [Barbell Bench Press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BBBenchPress.html) or [Push-up](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BWPushup.html) or [Dips](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BWChestDip.html) also use other muscles in different roles (synergist, stabilizer, etc).

Then, in a cutting phase, you can include some exercises which work chest in a more isolated way, and you can find them in the same link above.

It's also important to say that chest region has two different regions: [Pectoralis Mayor Sternal](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/PectoralisSternal.html) and [Clavicular](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/PectoralisClavicular.html), and you must exercise both sub-regions for a good result. If you already have a good level, with a well developed chest and if you looking for a higher level result, you should include in your routine some exercises which focus a little more on smaller sub-regions, as [Pectoralis Minor](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/PectoralisMinor.html) and [Serratus](http://www.exrx.net/Muscles/SerratusAnterior.html).

Just remembering: if we want to develop any region, with really notable results, we always should pay attention in all body regions: since calves to forearms, and associate all these training with a right diet, a nice quality sleep, etc (but these points are in other question).

Answer (score 0):

Some people have better genetics for creating a beautiful chest, some people will always have ugly chests. All we can do is make the most of what we're dealt.

Start out by working out your whole chest, increase muscle mass in pecs, delts as well as traps and lats, having nice abs will help as well. Also lower your body fat level to the level you prefer. When you've added enough weight, modify according to your tastes. Too small delts? Workout your delts, and so on.

It's not rocket science.

Comment: Do you have a picture of an ***ugly chest?*** Manboobs perhaps?

Comment: Well, some people are born with especially weird chests, like those who have gynecomastia, but  everyone isn't perfectly symmetrical with genetic traits that will let them grow in the right proportions, also, some people are almost non-responders to weight lifting.